# Research jobs in industry

Tags: phd, job

I have earned a PhD last year in materials science (semiconductor processing). Now I find myself in a job where most of the work is managing other people. To mee it seems like most of my former colleagues at university share the same fate.

What are your experiences? Have some of you found a job in industrial research which is really hands on like at university?
In particular I am interested in the field of semiconductor processing.

Comment: Who are those people you manage?  Are they those with less education than a Ph.D., but they have the hands-on research job you would prefer to have?

Comment: No. They do not have the hands-on research jobs I want. Basically I have to coordinate projects and have to talk to the experts of the processes that are involved and tell them what is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have all heard the old saw: "those who can, do; those who can't, manage". If that sums up your opinion, then you have two options: get a job as a basic researcher in industry (that is, as one of the people you currently manage) or in an appropriate academic environment (if you can find one that does not involve managing anybody).

You may, however, like to consider that some of the greatest scientific and technical achievements in the whole history of human activity have come from teams of individuals working together on a problem. Teams don't just work together automatically; they have to be managed. The skill of managing scientific research is to be prized:  by no means every brilliant researcher can do it, and very few so-called professional managers can do it either.

So, do not undervalue the importance of managing people.

Answer (score 1):

Consider technical staff jobs at a national lab.

That being said, the post-docs in my groups have had to learn that the technologists should be doing much of the hands-on work. That is what they are there for, that is what they are good at. The techs may need hands-on help for really new stuff, but they should do the vast majority of day-to-day stuff in the lab.

You, the PhD staff member, are not paid to optimize beam, or machine and build something. You are paid to think up new research topics, get funding for those, and oversee the project to successful completion (whether or not that includes publications). Yes, you get to think deep thoughts and analyze the data generated by the techs. Even then, the very best techs will do most of the data analysis for you. If somebody else can do it, let them - you should be doing the things nobody else can do.